# How to correctly populate records from SQLite in ListActivity?

Tags: android, sqlite

Can someone please tell me how can I easily display every record from sqllite in ListActivity tab? I'm kinda confused with this. Do I have to create db from my helper class in TabActivity or ListActivity or both? My db helper class is as follow:

```
package tabs.app;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter 
{

 private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/tabs.app/databases/";

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "coords";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "coordsStorages";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

   /* private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table coordsStorage (_id integer primary key autoincrement, latitude integer not null, longitude integer not null)";
     */   
    public Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL("create table coordsStorages (_id integer primary key autoincrement, latitude integer not null, longitude integer not null)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertCoords(int latitude, int longitude) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }


    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
          "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
          KEY_ROWID, 
          KEY_LATITUDE,
          KEY_LONGITUDE}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                  KEY_ROWID,
                  KEY_LATITUDE, 
                  KEY_LONGITUDE}, 
                  KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                  null,
                  null, 
                  null, 
                  null, 
                  null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a title---
    /*public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, int latitude, 
    int longitude) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);
        args.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }*/
}

And Im trying to retrieve the records in TabActivity like this:

public class Areas extends ListActivity {

 DBAdapter db;
 SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.areas_layout);

          db = new DBAdapter(this);
          db.open();
          Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
          startManagingCursor(c);

          String[] display = new String[] { db.KEY_LATITUDE };      
          int[] to = new int[] { R.id.row_latitude};
        /*
          String[] display2 = new String[] { db.KEY_LONGITUDE };      
          int[] to2 = new int[] { R.id.row_longitude};*/

          mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.areas_layout, c, display, to);
          setListAdapter(mAdapter);

       /*   mAdapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.areas_layout, c, display2, to2);
          setListAdapter(mAdapter2);*/

          db.close();



 }
/*
 private void fillData() {

     // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
     Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
     startManagingCursor(c);


 }*/

}
```

Whenever I'm trying to do that the error log outputs this:

```
06-07 09:51:56.529:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034): Uncaught
handler: thread main exiting due to
uncaught exception

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
start activity
ComponentInfo{tabs.app/tabs.app.Areas}:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your
content must have a ListView whose id
attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2242)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:631)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:317)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:127)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:346)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4133)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3672)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:850)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(    oneWindow.java:1712)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1202)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1987)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(    oneWindow.java:1696)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1658)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
Method)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034): Caused by:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your
content must have a ListView whose id
attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:236)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1620)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
tabs.app.Areas.onCreate(Areas.java:18)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)

06-07 09:51:56.559:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2034):     ... 30
more

06-07 09:51:56.619: INFO/Process(51):
Sending signal. PID: 2034 SIG: 3

06-07 09:51:56.619:
INFO/dalvikvm(2034): threadid=7:
reacting to signal 3

06-07 09:51:56.619:
ERROR/dalvikvm(2034): Unable to open
stack trace file
'/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission
denied
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your
content must have a ListView whose id
attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

This error is complaining that the ListView in your view file (R.layout.areas_layout) has not been given the correct id. Your ListView XML must look like this:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"…
```

Try doing that and see if it solves your problem:

****************Edit**************************************

Thanks for sharing your layout code, the problem seems to be that you have your list row xml layout in the same layout file as your main content view. You need to keep them seperate.

In your R.layout.areas_layout file just have your linearlayout and your listview then have a seperate xml file for your row which would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/row_latitude" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

You would then pass the list row to your SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_list_row, c, display, to);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've solved the problem I added the listview and the layout looks like this:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/row_latitude" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

So basically textView is above listview. Thx for the help mate!

Comment: See my edited post above. It's good practice to keep your list row xml seperate from the content view that your ListView is in. Glad you got it sorted, good luck with it